# JwtAuth is not generating tokens in Backpack Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-backpack

I am using backpack laravel. Though I am also using Backpack's own authentication, yet I need to maintain a different customer table for App usage. For the customer table, I am using JWTAuth for token generation, but token generation gets failed each time.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $checkEmail = Customer::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    
    if ($checkEmail) {
        $response = [
            'email_already_used' => true,
        ];
        return response()->json($response);
    }

    $payload = [
        'password' => \Hash::make($request->password),
        'email' => $request->email,
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'auth_token' => '',
    ];
   
    try {
        $user = new \App\Models\Customer($payload);
 
        if ($user->save()) {

            $token = self::getToken($request->email, $request->password); // generate user token
            
            if (!is_string($token)) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'data' => 'Token generation failed'], 201);
            }
            $user = \App\Models\Customer::where('email', $request->email)->get()->first();
            $user->auth_token = $token; // update user token
            $user->save();
           
            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'data' => [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'auth_token' => $token,
                    'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                    'email' => $user->email,                      
                ],
              
            ];
        } else {
            $response = ['success' => false, 'data' => 'Couldnt register user'];
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        echo ($e);
        $response = ['success' => false, 'data' => 'Couldnt register user.'];
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    }
    return response()->json($response, 201);
}
```

I believe there might be some issue with guards.
Do I need to specify something in app/config.php for this?

Comment: Have you follows these steps?
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

Comment: @WaqarAkram yes definitely..!

Comment: Hmmm I don't think this has anything to do with Backpack. Yes indeed - Backpack uses its own Auth guard and password broker - you can force Backpack to use the same as the stock Laravel auth inside `config/backpack/base.php` - search for `guard` and `password_broker`. But again... personally I don't see why Backpack would interfere with this, as long as it's not behind the `admin` middleware it's got nothing to do with it... Just my 2 cents.